# How can I trigger a custom event and use it's callback return value NOW?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, callback, event-handling

Normally I can do something similar (I could use array to manage multiple subscriptions) in vanilla js.

```
window.doCensorship = function($value, $proposal){return true};

function canPublish(text){
    var returnValue = (/* free speech */ true);
    if (typeof window.doCensorship === "function") {
       returnValue = window.doCensorship(text, returnValue);
    }
       return returnValue;
    }
}
```

But from what I have seen it seems JQuery has no notion of getting a value out of a custom event callback...

Did I miss some documentation? How can I do this in JQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I didn't search enough... `triggerHandler` with a object parameter seems one possible solution:

```
var r1 = {result:0};

$("#add-form").on("filter_results", function(e, data){
    data.result=41;
    return true;
});

$("#add-form").on("filter_results", function(e, data){
    data.result++;
    return true;
});

$("#add-form").triggerHandler("filter_results", [r1]);
console.log('[[',r1,']]');
```